# Google Ads stop loading after moving the project to a new machine

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have transferred my flutter app project from my old computer over to a new one. Since then I have not been able to load AdMob ads in my app.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))
```

I have seen similar questions with answers pointing at problems with signing the app. I have the key.properties file, and build.gradle set up as per Google's manual. I'm using my old key file I had previously generated on the old computer (is this the right way to do it??? or do I need a new file?). Still, only test ads are working. When I try using the real AdIDs, I'm getting the above message.

Before the transition to the new computer, everything worked just fine. Has anyone had this problem? Have I missed anything while moving the project?

In case it matters, I moved from a Windows laptop to a MacBook. I'm using the latest Flutter and Android Studio, as well as the latest version of the google_mobile_ads package.

Comment: You shouldn't use real ad IDs in testing environment or you'd be risking getting getting your admob account restricted because your app will be generating invalid impressions and possibly clicks. so always use test IDs, and test IDs are working then there's nothing to worry about, ads should be working fine in real world environment. If not, then check if you got any ad serving limitation or restriction from admob (you'll have an error message up top when you first enter the admob site)

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google has updated the SDK so that read ads are served only to apps signed with the Play Store key. This means they will only appear after the app is published and installed from the Play Store.